# Interpret MySQL column as a date interval unit?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, sql-order-by

When using Date and Time functions in MySQL, like [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add), is it possible to store the INTERVAL unit in a column and use it in a query?

For instance, consider the following table:

```
+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type                                              | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| snapshotSchedule_entry_id | int(10) unsigned                                  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| snapshotSchedule_id       | int(10) unsigned                                  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |                |
| everyFrequency            | smallint(5) unsigned                              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| everyInterval             | enum('minute','hour','day','week','month','year') | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| afterFrequency            | smallint(5) unsigned                              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| afterInterval             | enum('minute','hour','day','week','month','year') | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The following query works fine, because it is only dealing with the INTERVAL expression:

```
select * from snapshotSchedule_entry order by date_add(now(), interval everyFrequency month);
```

When I want to deal with the interval unit (e.g. month, year, etc), it does not interpret it.

> mysql> select * from snapshotSchedule_entry order by date_add(now(),
> interval 1 everyInterval);ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in
> your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
> server version for the right syntax to use near 'everyInterval)' at
> line 1

I'm not surprised by this behavior, I'm just curious if it's possible to make this work. It's not the end of the world to do this in code, but I wonder if it's possible.

Comment: Just to be clear, I know I could try and express some of these values as a number of seconds, or something like that... but that does not actually guarantee the ordering is correct. 1 month is not always going to occur before or after 30 days, for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is not that flexible with interval expressions. You would need a big `case` expression with hardcoded values:

```
order by case everyInterval
    when  'minute' then now() + inteval everyFrequency minute
    when  'hour'   then now() + inteval everyFrequency hour
    when  'day'    then now() + inteval everyFrequency day
    when  'week'   then now() + inteval everyFrequency week
    when  'month'  then now() + inteval everyFrequency month
    when  'year'   then now() + inteval everyFrequency year
end
```

A simpler alternative would be to redesign your schema to store the interval with fixed frequencies, say seconds and months. You could then do:

```
order by now() 
    + interval everyFrequencySecond second
    + interval everyFrequencyMonth  month
```

Comment: I actually came to the same conclusion since posting my question. I figured I could do nested IF conditions, then wondered if MySQL could do case like this. Anyway, your answer works perfectly. I think the fixed frequency approach doesn't work for my use case, because these rows refer to the idea that an entry could be created at any moment in the future, and this would indicate the order they would be created/deleted in.